Install the whole repository via pip
I want to install the whole repository as a package. I have a next structure
repo/
  ├── module.py
  └── pyproject.toml

and I need to use something like this after installing it python3 -m repo.module. What do I need to do that it installs in the repo folder?
my current pyproject.toml:
[project]
name = "repo"
version = "1.0.0"
requires-python = ">=3.11"
dependencies = [
]


[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]


You cannot do that with this directory structure. Please create a proper structure with a subdirectory for the package. You asked setuptools to find packages (importable directories) starting from the current directory but you don't have packages so nothing will be installed.
